# Multiple date of birth

Tags: visas, usa

Sometime in early 2000, I applied for student visa to study in the US with a wrong birth date on my admission letter and my freshly procured passport.

The agent that assisted in the admission brought forward my DOB to make it look like I am much younger. I complained to him, but I was so naive....I believe what he said that it won't affect anything.

I went for the interview three times within three years from year 2000 and was refused visa.

I didn't apply again until 2010. Meanwhile, the process and standard of procuring passport in my country changed from normal to e-passport.

I applied for it using my real DOB because I don't see why I should have a passport that would carry wrong info about me for life.

By 2010, I applied at the US embassy for a visa to visit siblings, not knowing the implications of using a different DOB. I was denied - no reason given.

I applied again and again four times in the next three years after 2010, But on the last appointment in 2013, the interviewer asked me for the first time why I used two different DOB. I told him I was ill-advised and was naive to know the implications.

He said he couldn't trust me and denied my application, and that was the last time I applied knowing why I have been refused all the years.

My question is: what are the implications? Does it mean I have been barred from entry into the US?

Comment: This is probably one of those situations where your best course of action would be to hire an attorney who specializes in US immigration law.

Comment: Unless you were barred for 212(a)(6)(C)(i) Material Misrepresentation / Fraud, you are not banned. Being denied 4 times in a row reflects a bigger issue than a different DOB.

Comment: Thanks people,but how do l know if barred under 212 (a)(6)(c)(i) Material Misrepresentation /Fraud,@greatone?